# What is the name of this keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I attached a picture of my keyboard (i.e. for a Dell Inspiron SE 7520). I'm running Ubuntu on it and I can't find neither the English not the Arabic layouts for this keyboard on Ubuntu by default.

Would someone help identifying the exact name of these 2 layouts ? Of course I expect only Arabs to able to help with the Arabic layout so it's not a problem to provide at least the name of one layout.

I've tried all possible English layouts but nothing worked. And tried a lot of Arabic layouts too.

The Answer (Thanks to Rudu)

- **Arabic:** Arabic (102) AZERTY
- **English:** US English (IBM Arabic 238_L)

[image]

Comment: I don't see a picture???......

Comment: @Xavierjazz, sorry, it's attached now. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana I didn't find Arabic 102 layout, Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install Ubuntu there's a process that lets you type keys so the software knows what keyboard you use... did that not work?  [Perhaps it's only good for latin languages]

Anyway, the easiest way online is [MS: Windows Keyboard Layouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964651.aspx) it's a bit tedious (you have to choose a keyboard and wait for the image to load) but there's lots in there.  I'd start with the `Arabic 101`, `Arabic 102`, `Arabic 102 Azerty` options

Comment: This is awesome ! Thanks A LOT ! Do you know from where can I download these missing layouts for Ubuntu ?

Comment: If you're using a GUI there's a handy guide here: [How-To Geek: Add Keyboard Input Language to Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17508/add-keyboard-input-language-to-ubuntu/)

Comment: This is for an older version. The one I have now doesn't have it. I'm using v13.10

Comment: It's called *Text Entry Settings..* in your version, almost identical process though

Comment: In the text entry settings in my version, I can only chose a different layout from a list in which I can't find the names you kindly guided me to. And I can't edit these layouts.

Comment: @Rudu I didn't find Arabic 102 , Ubuntu 18